# Geolocation unit test with JsTestDriver

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm testing geolocation using JsTestDriver, this is my code:

```
GeoLocationTest.prototype.testLocation = function(){
    expectAsserts(1);
    var coordinate = new Coordinate();
    var location = coordinate.getLocation();
    assertEquals("1,1",location);
};
```

Te test always fails because it tests immediately, before getting the geolocation coordinates. I tried using a timeout but the test also executes immediately.

```
setTimeout(function(){assertEquals("1,1",location);},10000);
```

And this is the javascript I'm trying to test

```
function Coordinate () {
    this.latitude = 0.0;
    this.longitude = 0.0;
    this.date = new Date();
    this.errorMsg = "";
} 

Coordinate.prototype.getLocation = function(){
    if (this.isBrowserSupported()){ //this test passes
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setPosition,this.setError);
        return "" + this.latitude + "," + this.longitude;
    }
    return "Browser not supported";
}

Coordinate.prototype.setPosition = function(position){
   this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
   this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

AssertError: expected "1,1" but was "0,0"

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrong, hate JS

```
function Coordinate () {
    latitude = 0.0;
    longitude = 0.0;
    date = new Date();
    errorMsg = "";
} 

Coordinate.prototype.getLocation = function(){
    if (this.isBrowserSupported()){ //this test passes
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setPosition,this.setError);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

Coordinate.prototype.setPosition = function(position){
   Coordinate.prototype.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
   Coordinate.prototype.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

And then the test

```
GeoLocationTest.prototype.testLocation = function(){
    var timeout = 10000;
    expectAsserts(2);
    var coordinate = new Coordinate();
    coordinate.getLocation();
    setTimeout(function(){
        assertEquals(1,Coordinate.prototype.latitude);
        assertEquals(1,Coordinate.prototype.longitude);
        console.log("testLocation finished");
    },timeout);
};
```

JsTestDriver will output "AssertError: Expected '2' asserts but '0' encountered."

So open the browser, open the console and wait for the test to execute. I added the last log because if the test passes nothing happens, if it fails it outputs the failure.