# Ionic unit testing geolocation fails

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Trying to unit test my new ionic2 application fails after adding the geolocation test cases. Here is a minimum example: https://github.com/geoHeil/ioni2GeolocationUnitTest

The error can be reproduced by running `npm test`

```
TypeScript error: app/services/geo/geolocation.service.spec.ts(30,38): Error TS2339: Property 'Coordinates' does not exist on type 'typeof ".../node_modules/ionic-native/dist/plugins/geolocation"'.
```

strangely even though I specified:

```
import  * as NativeGeo  from 'ionic-native/dist/plugins/geolocation';
```

this type definition seems to be used

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 2016.2\ EAP.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/typescriptCompiler/external/lib.d.ts
```

## edit

I just found [Geolocation unit test with JsTestDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817627/geolocation-unit-test-with-jstestdriver) which might be slightly related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it creating my own implementation of coordinates, like:

```
class MyCoordinates implements Coordinates {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    accuracy: number;
    altitude: number;
    altitudeAccuracy: number;
    heading: number;
    speed: number;
}
```